# Collapse Computed Properties and Property Observers in editor?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, editor

Is it possible to collapse this:

```
var index:Int = 0 {
    willSet { }
    didSet { }
}
```

and this:

```
var index:Int {
    get { }
    set { }
}
```

... in XCode 6 yet?

Im using XCode 6.1.1 which I believe is the latest but I cant find any settings for collapsing those parts and its kind of annoying actually.

Is there a hidden setting or something like that or will I just have to wait for apple to realize this and implement it in a future version?

Comment: Not happening in xcode 7 :( please implement this!

Answer (score 0):

Filed it as bug / improvement feature #24855572

Comment: I have aswell... 1 year ago... no answer yet from Apple

Comment: filed it too ... so annoying, it renders the whole code folding feature a bit useless in Swift